# Название сигнальной кнопки при пожаре

Tags: грамотная-речь

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как назвается эта застекленная кнопка и выступающая коробочка, к которой она присоединена?

Answer (score 1):

Так и называется - пожарная кнопка, или кнопка пожарной сигнализации.

https://bezopasnostin.ru/pozharnaya-signalizatsiya/knopka-pozharnoj-signalizatsii.html